# Google finance record Json Parsing vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am creating vb.net application. I am getting Json data from google finance. I am facing a problem in parsing. The problem is that :
I will give an example (not about google)

This is the class

```
Public Class MyModel

    Dim m_tes As String
    Dim m_client_list As String

    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return m_tes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_tes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property client_list() As String
        Get
            Return m_client_list
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_client_list = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and this is the JSON Deserializer

```
Dim deserializedProduct As MyModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyModel)(JSON)
MsgBox(deserializedProduct.type)
MsgBox(deserializedProduct.client_list)
```

If I get one record Json data ,It works fine
like

```
 dim JSON =   {"type":"newModel","client_list":"Joe"}
```

The output of the msgbox is

newModel

Joe

The problem is that if I get a list of Json 
I need a way to split this list likeh the following:

```
 Json =  {"type":"clientlist","client_list":"client 1"},{"type":"clientlist","client_list":"client 1"}
```

Comment: I just wanna split this string

     {"type":"clientlist","client_list":"client 1"},{"type":"clientlist","client_list":"client 1"}

Comment: Why not make another object that holds a collection of the items you want to split, and pass *that* object into the deserializer?

Comment: Thats what I want , but how ?

Comment: See my answer below. `List(Of T)` is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked a whole lot with JSON, but I think you can pass a collection into the deserializer to get a back a collection of the deserialized objects.

In other words:

```
Dim deserializedProduct As List(Of MyModel) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyModel))(JSON)
```

The above code is similar to what you posted, except that is uses `List<T>` instead of a single instance of your `MyModel` object, and for the type used with the `DeserializeObject` you give it a `List(Of ModelType`).

Note that your `MsgBox(deserializedProduct.type)` and `MsgBox(deserializedProduct.client_list)` won't show you the results in a `List<T>` (you'll get the type name instead) - you'll need to loop through the list.  Something like this:

```
For Each Dim model As MyModel In deserializedProduct
   MsgBox(model.type)
   MsgBox(model.client_list)
Next
```

Comment: Thats helpful, but should I split the string before deserialization ?

Comment: If yes , How can I split it ?

Comment: @user3471633 - No, I'd leave the string as is.  When the JSON is deserialized it should return it as a `List(Of T)`.